# Kotlin - Type of `if` and `when` Expressions

Tags: kotlin, jvm, static-typing

I understand that Kotlin is a statically-typed language, and all the types are defined at the compile time itself.

Here is a `when` expression that returns different types:

```
fun main(){

    val x = readLine()?.toInt() ?: 0

    val y = when(x){
        1 -> 42
        2 -> "Hello"
        else -> 3.14F
    }

    println(y::class.java)
}
```

During runtime (Kotlin 1.3.41 on JVM 1.8) this is the output:

When `x` = 1, it prints `class java.lang.Integer`

When `x` = 2, it prints `class java.lang.String`

Otherwise, it prints `class java.lang.Float`

When does the compiler determine the type of `y`? Or, how does the compiler infers the type of `y` during compile-time?

Comment: Most likely `y` is typed as `Any`, which is the common supertype of all the types. In other words, with explicit typing it'd look like `val y: Any = when(x) {...}`.

Comment: @Slaw That's what I guessed, but wondering how `Any` is converted to `Integer`, `String` etc. in the `println(y::class.java)` statement.

Comment: It's not. There's a difference between the _declared type_ of a variable and the _actual type_ of the object it references. It's no different than doing `val x: Any = "Hello, Wold!";`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, the type of the when expression resolves to `Any` in this case, so the `y` variable can have any value. An IDE even warns you, that `Conditional branch result of type X is implicitly cast to Any`, at least Android Studio does, as well as [Kotlin Playground](https://pl.kotl.in/O0Ly0XJ2L).

Comment: And in general, it resolves to the nearest common supertype of all the types concerned.  If, for example, branches returned a `List` and a `Set`, then the resulting type would be `Collection` (and similarly, its type parameter would be the nearest common supertype of those).  (Though, oddly enough, that doesn't seem to hold for the numeric types; you'd expect it to infer `Number` for `Int` and `Float`, but it infers `Any`.  Not sure why…)

Answer (score 2):

The type of that variable for you is `Any` (as the smallest possible superclass for all that types), but underlying value is untouched.

What does it mean? You can safely access only properties that are common for all that types (so only properties available for `Any` type. And property `::class.java` is available for all types.

See this example - I use some other types to good visualise what is it about.

```
abstract class FooGoo {
    fun foogoo(): String = "foo goo"
}

class Foo: FooGoo() {
    fun foo(): String = "foo foo"
}

class Goo: FooGoo() {
    fun goo(): String = "goo goo"
}

class Moo {
    fun moo(): String = "moo moo"
}

fun main(x: Int) {
    val n = when (x) {
        0 -> Foo()
        1 -> Goo()
        else -> throw IllegalStateException()
    } // n is implicitly cast to FooGoo, as it's the closes superclass of both, Foo and Goo

    // n now has only methods available for FooGoo, so, only `foogoo` can be called (and all methods for any)

    val m = when (x) {
        0 -> Foo()
        1 -> Goo()
        else -> Moo()
    } // m is implicitly cast to Any, as there is no common supertype except Any

    // m now has only methods available for Any() - but properties for that class are not changed
    // so, `m::class.java` will return real type of that method.

    println(m::class.java) // // Real type of m is not erased, we still can access it

    if (m is FooGoo) { 
        m.foogoo() // After explicit cast we are able to use methods for that type.
    }
}
```

Comment: Great explanation! So the `when` expression returns the minimal possible superclass, which makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

During compile-time, the inferred type of `y` is `Any` which is the supertype of all types in Kotlin. During run-time, `y` can reference [literally] any type of object. The IDE generates a warning `"Conditional branch result of type Int/String/Float is implicitly cast to Any"`.

In the example,

When `x` = 1, it refers to an object of type `java.lang.Integer`.

When `x` = 2, it refers to an object of type `java.lang.String`.

Otherwise, it refers to an object of type `java.lang.Float`.

---

*Thanks [Slaw](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58479824/kotlin-type-of-if-and-when-expressions#comment103292062_58479824) for the quick explanation:*

> There's a difference between the **declared type** of a variable and the **actual type** of the object it references. It's no different than doing `val x: Any = "Hello, Wold!"`;